# Is careers appropriate for seeking a management-only job?

Tags: discussion, jobs

In my current position I program, I sysadmin, and manage programmers.

I want my next position to be full-time technical management.  Is careers.stackoverflow.com an appropriate venue for me to advertise my services for a *management only* position, or is careers meant exclusively for those who are *doing the technical work*?

Comment: @Bart - John means: is careers an appropriate venue to advertise himself as a candidate for a position which is entirely management, or is careers meant exclusively for those who are doing the technical work?  I know this because John and I work together and talked about this; I'm the one that suggested he ask here.  I'll edit the question to make it more clear; this comment is to (hopefully) make it clear that the edit I'm going to do in a few moments is not out of line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**John**, what's been communicated to me is that if the management role manages developers and/or requires a technical background, then you're fine. As you can I see, I found [more](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/62344/engineering-manager-platform-team-new-relic?a=1e29XV0UE&searchTerm=manager) [than a](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/61791/hris-program-manager-amazon?a=1dmlq2uiY&searchTerm=manager) [few](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/61232/sr-manager-software-development-amazon?a=1cG4KauwU&searchTerm=manager) [jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/48180/manager-of-software-development-adp-corporate?a=WL91pMKQ&searchTerm=manager) [this](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/58548/engineering-manager-advertise-reporting-platform-quantcast?a=19p7KEIfK&searchTerm=manager) [morning](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/58561/senior-technical-program-manager-cloud-data-symantec-cloud-platform?a=19q6HiTMA&searchTerm=manager) like this.